# Rails Pundit Authorization not performed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, pundit

I'm getting an "Pundit::PolicyScopingNotPerformedError" when calling a GET request to the show method of this controller. Any help appreciated.

Controller:

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize_dashboard_for_customer, only: :show
  after_action :verify_authorized, except: :index
  after_action :verify_policy_scoped, only: :show

  expose(:dashboards) {
    Customer.find(params[:customer_id]).dashboards
  }

  expose(:dashboard) {
    Dashboard.find(params[:id])
  }

  expose(:customer) {
    Customer.find(params[:customer_id])
  }

  def index
  end

  def show
  end



  private

  def authorize_dashboard_for_customer
    authorize dashboard, :show?
  end  
end
```

Here is the Pundit Policy:

```
class DashboardPolicy < ApplicationPolicy

  def index?
    show?
  end

  def show?
    customer = user.try(:customer)
    return false if customer.blank?

    @record.customers.present? && @record.customers.include?(customer) || user.role == 'admin'
  end
end
```

I've read other posts about this, but still not seeing what I'm doing wrong here. I'm still fuzzy on what resolving a policy scope is doing, but in this case I can see from debug statements that it's hitting the policy, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you're checking to make sure the policy scope is called with `after_action :verify_policy_scoped, only: :show` but you aren't calling anything for the scope in your action.

You can use [Scopes](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#scopes) to restrict the results based on the logged in users permissions. For instance an admin user on an index screen would likely see all the results, but a non-admin could maybe only see certain records. IMO you shouldn't need scopes on a show so you should be able to remove the `verify_policy_scoped`.

Comment: Thanks - that helps some. @Scott - you say _but you aren't calling anything for the scope in your action_  - would I call this scope in the policy method or in the controller method?

Comment: @andrew You'll add the scope class to your policy class and then call it from the controller to retrieve the records.